# Update single UICollectionviewCell from VC

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, reloaddata

So I have a VC that allows ppl to send a friend request to any of the users listed in a collectionview and I want to switch from a add button to a loading indicator while the request is waiting on a response , but im not sure how to do this without calling  [self.collectionview reloadData] , is there a way to temp change the appearance of a single cell w. out reloading the entire collectionview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the UICollectionViewCell pointer - call

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:cell];
[self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Method `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths` as-

```
[self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPathOfYourCell]];
```